Weird manipulation using log-sum inequality
This is going to be a simple question. The statement is simple:
Given a probability vector $a$ and a doubly stochastic matrix $P$ which satisfies
$$\sum_{i}P_{ij} = 1 = \sum_{j} P_{ij}$$
, then $b = aP$ is again a probability vector and,
$$H(b) \geq H(a)$$
$H(a), H(b)$ are just entropy. The proof goes as follows:
$$H(b) - H(a) = -\sum_{j} b_j\log b_j + \sum_{i} a_i\log a_i$$
$$= -\sum_{i, j} a_iP_{ij}\log\bigg(\sum_{k} a_{k}P_{kj}\bigg) + \sum_{i, j}a_iP_{ij}\log a_i$$
$$= \sum_{i, j} a_iP_{ij}\log\bigg(a_i \bigg/\sum_{k} a_{k}P_{kj}\bigg)$$
$$\geq \bigg(\sum_{i, j} a_iP_{ij}\bigg)\log\bigg(\frac{\sum_{i, j} a_{j}}{\sum_{i, j} b_j}\bigg)$$
$$= (1)\log\frac{m}{m} = 0$$
, where $m$ being the length of $a$ and $b$. It proves $H(b) \geq H(a)$. How is the inequality an application of Log sum. I can't quite figure it out.
Here's the original derivation:


There is indeed a little fix needed. The log sum inequality states:
$$ \sum_t c_t \log \frac{c_t}{d_t} \ge C \log \frac{C}{D}$$ where $C = \sum c_t$
and $D = \sum d_t$.
Let $c_t = a_i P_{i,j}$ where $t$ runs over all the pairs $i,j$.
Then notice that the fraction inside the log is
$$\frac{a_i}{\sum_{k} a_{k}P_{kj}} =
\frac{a_i}{b_j}=
\frac{a_i P_{i,j}}{b_j P_{i,j}} =  \frac{c_t}{d_t}$$
Then $C  = \sum_{t} c_t = \sum_{i,j} a_i P_{i,j} = \sum_{i} a_i u = 1$ and
similarly $D=1$.

I doubt this works.  Since $t$ is not supposed to be 2d. Also, it does not quite fit well with the derivation in my question. Could you elaborate on that? I'll edit to post the original derivation.

"$t$  is not supposed to be 2d" What? The LSI deals with a (finite) set of numbers, it does not matter how you index them.

Right. Thats tricky in a simple way. Lol
